# oracle.xml.parser.v2.XSLProcessor.processXSL overload seems to do nothing

Tags: java, oracle, xslt

I'm trying to chain multiple XSL transforms together using the Oracle [XSLProcessor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28391/oracle/xml/parser/v2/XSLProcessor.html).

The first transform runs fine.  The second transform also appears to run, but does not change the output at all.

This is the code I'm using for the first transform.

```
private static XMLDocumentFragment Transform(InputStream xslt_stream, InputStream src_xml_stream) throws XSLException, MalformedURLException{
    XSLProcessor proc = new XSLProcessor();
    XSLStylesheet stylesheet = proc.newXSLStylesheet(xslt_stream);

    XMLDocumentFragment frag = proc.processXSL(stylesheet, src_xml_stream, null);

    return frag;
}
```

I take the output of that transform and pipe it into the second method.

```
private static XMLDocumentFragment Transform(InputStream xslt_stream, XMLDocumentFragment src_frag) throws XSLException, MalformedURLException{
    XSLProcessor proc = new XSLProcessor();
    XSLStylesheet stylesheet = proc.newXSLStylesheet(xslt_stream);

    XMLDocumentFragment frag = proc.processXSL(stylesheet, src_frag);

    return frag;
}
```

Here is the flow.

```
// get XSL input stream from ZD
xslt_stream = getFromZD(conn, "SELECTFF", zd_xslt_chain_1);

    // first overload
XMLDocumentFragment transformed = Transform(xslt_stream, xml_stream);

if (zd_xslt_chain_2 !=  null){
    // run second in transform chian
    xslt_stream = getFromZD(conn, "SELECTFF", zd_xslt_chain_2);

            // second overload
    transformed = Transform(xslt_stream, transformed);
}
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong and is there a better way to run an XSLT chain?  Lets pretend like I have use Oracle's XSL processor, because I do.